# Lastlogon - Should it sync accross all domain controlers

Tags: active-directory

Im using [LastLogon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676824(VS.85).aspx) attribute to check when a user account last was used, but i see the value seems to be updated on each DC when a user logs in via that DC. And its NOT synced across the different domain controlers.

So my question is:
Is this how this attribute should work? Or is it something wrong in our domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lastLogonTimeStamp` attribute is automatically replicated across all domain DCs only if the domain is (at least) at Windows Server 2003 functional level.

Also, beware of differences between `lastLogonTimeStamp` and `lastLogon` (the latter one is obsolete and never replicated).

http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The LastLogon attribute **is not** replicated. When the domain functional level is "Windows Server 2003" there is a new attribute "lastLogonTimeStamp" which **is** replicated.

Comment: He wrote "LastLogon", but actually linked "lastLogonTimeStamp".

Comment: He is correct also. I was actualy checking both, but assumed the LastLogon was correct one to use ( And used lastLogonTimeStamp as a fallback).